# Checkout from umerged branch github

Tags: github

I was wondering what the best way to create a new branch from an unmerged branch it github was. Is it as simple as:

```
git checkout the_unmerged_branch

git checkout -b the_new_branch
```

I have not found a answer for this so far and I am concerned doing the above may mess up things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

git checkout the_unmerged_branch
add and commit 
git checkout -b the_new_branch
and fetch your origin handle and merge if this is your desire to update this branch with origin 
handle the merge errors if there is 
And 
if you screw up git reset --hard